# Como sinalizar respostas em outro idioma?

Tags: debate, sinalização

Recentemente vi uma **resposta** que estava em inglês, desde de o fim de 2018, [Passar a senha do certificado v](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/267710/passar-a-senha-do-certificado-v/352804#352804) (a resposta foi removida, então requer privilégio para visualiza-la).

---

Eu sinalizei como "requer atenção dos moderadores" e escrevi "Não está em português.". Porém, a sinalização foi rejeitada. Entretanto, a resposta sinalizada foi apagada (não sei se antes ou depois da revisão da sinalização).

A sinalização foi recusada contendo:

> rejeitado - Usar sinalizações padrões ajuda-nos priorizar problemas e resolvê-las mais rápido. Por favor familiarize-se com a lista de sinalizações padrões: veja O que é Sinalizar?

---

A pergunta é:

1. Se a sinalização foi recusada, porque a resposta também foi apagada?
2. Qual seria a "sinalização padrão" que deveria utilizar?

   Existem apenas: `spam`, `rude ou abusivo` e `não é uma resposta`. Seria "não é uma resposta" a correta?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Foi erro meu mesmo, achei que era uma pergunta, aí quando vi que era resposta e não tem outro jeito de sinalizar era para eu ter aceitado a sinalização correta, mas não tinha mais o que fazer, me desculpe, eu fui infeliz. Para respostas, é a forma correta de fazer.

O "Não é uma resposta" pode ser interessante também, porque dá pra ver o motivo de não ser uma resposta, mas não sei se todo moderador entenderá assim, porque de certa forma é uma resposta.

Eu só apaguei porque o AR foi alertado que a resposta deveria ser em português e nada fez. Ninguém mais se prontificou a traduzir, então não dá para manter isso no site nessas condições.