# Por quê as perguntas em outro idioma não são sinalizadas como "não está em Português"?

Tags: debate, fechamento, idioma

Costumo ver perguntas em outro idioma (a grande maioria em inglês) serem fechadas por divermos motivos como "sobre algoritmos" (a maioria também), e não entendo a razão disso, já que existe uma opção específica para esses casos que é "Essa pergunta não pertence ao site porque **não está em Português**".

Não deveríamos usar essa opção?

Vejo também que as pessoas às vezes comentam ou até respondem quando está em inglês porque é um idioma bem conhecido, mas seria assim se estivesse em outro idioma qualquer?

Acho que se a opção existe, essas perguntas deveriam ser categorizadas como tal, ou então deveríamos rever essa opção ao sinalizar para ser fechada, isso porque a mensagem de fechamento com outras opções vai induzir o usuário a mudar a pergunta, ainda no mesmo idioma, quando na verdade a primeira coisa a ser feita seria traduzí-la.

Já li as perguntas relacionadas, e pelo que ví não há um entendimento diferente desse que estou abordando que é sinalizar essas perguntas com essa opção:

[Como sinalizar respostas em outro idioma](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8640/como-sinalizar-respostas-em-outro-idioma)

[O que fazer com perguntas em um outro idioma?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1031/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-em-um-outro-idioma)

Comment: Só pra adiantar o assunto: quando o único problema é a língua, normalmente fechamos com a opção que mencionou. O problema é que a mensagem é específica sobre traduzir para reabrir, e se a pergunta tem mais problemas (como ser ampla, não clara etc) melhor fechar pelo motivo final, que permanecerá mesmo se traduzida, e avisar nos comentários que precisa ser em português. Senão acabam sendo dois fechamentos, um pela língua ai tem que reabrir e fechar de novo por outra razão, o que além de dar mais mão de obra, frustra mais o autor da pergunta que traduziu e não conseguiu manter a postagem aberta.

Comment: é um bom ponto @Bacco, nesse caso seria interessante se alguém sinalizar pra fechar por outro motivo que não seja o idioma que coloque tbm um comentário pra ajudar nesse ponto, senão a pessoa vai editar, melhorar a pergunta e manter em inglês  ou outro idioma :)

aliás, se fosse em outro idioma provavelmete as pessoas não entenderiam e sinalizariam de outra forma

Comment: Relacionado (talvez dup?): https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7108/112052

Comment: @hkotsubo me parece dup mesmo, o que acha, Ricardo?

Comment: boa, essa outra pergunta inclusive está bem mais "completa", podemos fechar :)